# Perl Getopt Using Same Option Multiple Times

Tags: perl, getopt

In Perl `getopts`, is it possible to use the same option multiple times but with different values ? I want to give the user the option of entering different grid coordinates but uses the same option name to minimize confusion.

Ex:

```
my_grid.pl --coords=10,12 --coords=-18,30 --coords=4,-25
```

The script would then perform a set of actions on those different pairs. There will always be at least one pair but there is no knowing how many pairs from situation to situation.

I would like to avoid: `--coords1= --coords2= --coords3=` and so on. I do not know how to deal with the unknown quantity of coords pairs with that `1` and `2` and `3` method anyway. I have used `getopts` in previous projects but am getting into more complex demands/issues. I tried to search for solutions/examples but probably used the wrong keywords. Thnx for any assist.

Rod

Comment: If you're using GetOpt::Long: http://search.cpan.org/~jv/Getopt-Long-2.42/lib/Getopt/Long.pm#Options_with_multiple_values  This will allow each `--coords=...` to be added to an array that holds all of them, which you can then iterate over.

Answer (score 9):

As documented in [`Getopts::Long` - Options with multiple values](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Options-with-multiple-values):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;

GetOptions(
    "coords=s" => \my @coords,
);

print "$_\n" for @coords;
```

Executed using:

```
my_grid.pl --coords=10,12 --coords=-18,30 --coords=4,-25
```

Outputs:

```
10,12
-18,30
4,-25
```

Comment: It is getopt long. Thnx much to you both.