# Perl6 sub MAIN/ command line Parsing

Tags: raku

In Perl 5, I was able to set an option multiple times like in this question:

[Perl Getopt Using Same Option Multiple Times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346520/perl-getopt-using-same-option-multiple-times)

I am wondering if it's possible to do the same with Perl 6 and the MAIN sub ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you define your named parameters as an array then it just works :

```
perl6 -e 'sub MAIN( :@test ) { say @test }' --test=1 --test=2 --test=3
[1 2 3]
```

Comment: That's exact l'y what I was looking for. Perl6 have à lot of Nice features. I think I will use for developing my projet. Thank you very much !

Comment: No problem. I wasn't sure it would work. You should be able to apply constraints to the values too using a where clause.